# how to implement dot placeholder in custom pipe?

Tags: r

I'm writing my custom pipe and I would like it to work similar to %>%:

using this:

```
abc <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
abc %mypipe% data.frame(a = ., b= 2 *., c = 3*.) %mypipe% filter(b>6)
```

I'd like to get this:

```
  a  b  c
1 4  8 12
2 5 10 15
3 6 12 18
4 7 14 21
```

I was able to define %mypipe%, but my code fails when I use dot.

```
`%mypipe%` <-
  function (lhs, rhs) {
    rhs_call <- substitute(rhs)
    eval(rhs_call, envir = list(. = lhs), enclos = parent.frame())
  }
```

Comment: Can you please also share the code for your `%mypipe%` function?

Comment: This issue is the call to ```filter``` - the code does not  force the lhs as the first argument of the rhs.

Comment: @Cole do you know how to make a pipe force it?

Comment: If you want it to behave like ```%>%```, then you should probably look at the ```magrittr``` package source code. As is, I think @AllenCameron did a great job.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing the dot placeholder is harder than implementing the pipe, since you need to recursively replace captured dots in expressions within the pipe calls. It all gets a bit difficult to reason about. You even have to recursively build and `eval` calls to your own dot-replacing function inside itself.

The following is a (roughly) working implementation:

```r
replace_dot <- function(x, y) {
  x <- match.call()$x
  y <- match.call()$y
  
  if(is.symbol(x)) 
    if(as.character(x) == ".")
      return(y)
    else return(x)
  
  if(is.call(x))
  {
    x_list <- as.list(x)[-1]
    if(length(x_list) > 0)
      if(as.character(x_list[[1]])[1] == "." & 
         as.character(as.list(x)[[1]])[1] != "$")
        x_list <- x_list[-1]
    
    for(i in seq_along(x_list)) {
      x_list[[i]] <- eval(as.call(list(quote(replace_dot),
                                       x = x_list[[i]], y = substitute(y))))
    }
    return(as.call(c(x[[1]], x_list)))   
  }
  else return(x)
}

`%mypipe%` <- function(a, b)
{
  mc   <- as.list(match.call())
  mc$b <- eval(as.call(list(quote(replace_dot), x = mc$b, y = substitute(a))))
  mc$b <- as.call(append(as.list(mc$b), mc$a, 1))

  eval(as.call(mc$b), envir = parent.frame())
}
```

So now we can do:

```
abc %mypipe% data.frame(a = ., b= 2 *., c = 3*.) %mypipe% select(c,b) 
#>    c  b
#> 1  3  2
#> 2  6  4
#> 3  9  6
#> 4 12  8
#> 5 15 10
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work properly with e.g.  cbind.

Comment: @IziBizi If I do `abc %>% cbind(.)` I get a matrix with 2 columns of `abc`, which is what I would expect. What do you mean "it doesn't work"?

Comment: when I do ```abc %>% cbind(., data.frame(d = .$c *2 )) ``` my output has abc columns  twice. Of course it works if I put {cbind()}, but do you think I could get it properly without using these brackets?

Comment: @IziBizi but why are you putting the first dot? In a pipe operator, the left hand side is passed as the first argument, so doing `abc %>% cbind(., data.frame(d = .$c * 2))` is the same as writing `cbind(abc, abc, data.frame(d = .$c * 2))` . You are getting abc twice because you are asking for it twice. Try just `abc %>% cbind(data.frame(d = .c$ * 2))`

Comment: I see you point and you're totally right but %>% somehow suppresses calling it twice and that's what I'm trying to get but can't figure out how.

Comment: I would really appreciate your help here

Comment: @IziBizi that adds another layer of complexity on. Can I ask why you're doing it this way? if you want to replicate the pipe operator why not use the pipe operator's source code? I can understand you wanting to write your own pipe operator as a learning exercise, but what benefit is there in getting someone to write one for you? I don't mind the challenge, but it would be good to know what I was doing it for...

Comment: A part of my homework is to replicate pipe operator. Without it I can't turn in anything. I've been dealing with it for almost 2 months and as a last resort I decided to ask here. I would never ask someone to do my job for me, but I tried everything and can't find the right answer. Hence I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Wow. That's a tough homework assignment. So it has to behave in an identical way to the actual pipe operator?

Comment: Yes, the same as %>%

Comment: @IziBizi see my update. If the first argument to any function within the pipe is ".", it will be replaced by the piped variable. I'm sure this version has to be good enough for any undergrad homework assignment.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I tried this ```abc %mypipe% data.frame(a = .) %mypipe% cbind(., data.frame(b = .$a*2))``` and got Error in a$NULL : 1 argument passed to '$' which requires 2

Comment: @IziBizi I have fixed that issue. Please remember the actual pipe operator requires several related functions that have been evolved and tested over the years. It is not really reasonable to expect a full replica in a Stack Overflow answer. I think this will handle most use cases and should get you a good grade. You should study it so you can tweak if necessary. Good luck!